# show name of file on custom input field

Tags: html, css

i am using a custom file input on an upload page on my website and it is working as per my requirement the only issue is i have hidden the default layout of filetype="input" but i want to show the name of the file being uploaded so that the user may know which file he has uploadedand  the name of the file here's the fiddle

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tk27sk6q/)

here's the html and css

```
<div class="custom-upload">
  <div class="fake-file">
   <input placeholder="Choose File" type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" />
  </div>
 </div>

.custom-upload {
    position: relative;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #625f5b;
}

.custom-upload input[type=file]
{
    outline:none;
    position: relative;
    text-align: right;
    -moz-opacity:0 ;
    filter:alpha(opacity: 0);
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;

}

.custom-upload .fake-file
{
    background:url(https://s4.postimg.org/hy3g354ot/upload.png) center right no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    line-height: 100%;
}

.custom-upload .fake-file input
{
    font-size:16px;
    height:40px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Is this enough:
https://jsfiddle.net/tk27sk6q/4/

Comment: yea thats great but how will i show it to a hidden field?

Comment: Do you mean you have a hidden input and want to put the name of the file as value?

Comment: exactly! the type="file" is hidden because i dont want to show that creepy choose file button but i still want the name to be displayed as value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the JavaScript I added.

**Note:** I used jQuery. If you are using native JavaScript, I have to change the code

```js
$(function(){
  $("#fileToUpload").on('change',function(){
    fpath = $(this).val();
    $('#filePath').html('<b>You selected the file:</b> ' + fpath);
  });
});
```

```css
.custom-upload {
    position: relative;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #625f5b;
}

.custom-upload input[type=file]
{
    outline:none;
    position: relative;
    text-align: right;
    -moz-opacity:0 ;
    filter:alpha(opacity: 0);
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;

}

.custom-upload .fake-file
{
    background:url(https://s4.postimg.org/hy3g354ot/upload.png) center right no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    line-height: 100%;
}

.custom-upload .fake-file input
{
    font-size:16px;
    height:40px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom-upload">
  <div class="fake-file">
    <input placeholder="Choose File" type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" />
  </div>
  <div id="filePath">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @uneebmeer, (thumbsup)

Answer (score 0):

Another choise could be without using jquery, but pure javascript. This is my solution.

```
<span id='filename'></span>
<div class="custom-upload">
  <div class="fake-file">
    <input placeholder="Choose File" type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" />
  </div>
</div>
<script>
    document.getElementById('fileToUpload').addEventListener('change', function() { 
    var dest = document.getElementById('filename');
    dest.innerHTML = document.getElementById('fileToUpload').value;
  });
</script>
```

I let you the personalization of css of the elements to fit your needs.
Hope this help.